# What is the purpose of the Volume Master Key in BitLocker?

Tags: encryption, windows, key-management, disk-encryption, bitlocker

From this [FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-key-management-faq), I understand that BitLocker uses the following keys to encrypt the hard-drive:

- Full Volume Encryption Key (FVEK) (used to encrypt raw data; encrypted by the volume master key and stored on-disk)
- Volume Master Key (VMK) (encrypted by a key protector and stored on-disk)
- Key Protector (KP) (TPM or numerical password)

I don't understand what security value the VMK provides. Why not just encrypt the FVEK directly using KPs?

In any case, if a KP leaks, the FVEK can be obtained anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering about the same thing myself, did some googling around, until found the answer here:
[BitLocker : Update Volume Master Key and meaning of "keyed" vs "re-keyed"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97636/bitlocker-update-volume-master-key-and-meaning-of-keyed-vs-re-keyed)
[Microsoft's docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732774(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#bitlocker-concepts)

Basically, use of intermediate key (VMK between FVEK and KPs) is to allow the change of keys if KPs are compromised without the need of re-encrypting the (encrypted) data itself.
KPs compromised -> create new (KPs and) VMK -> encrypt old FVEK with new VMK

Then, attacker with old KPs will get to the old VMK and trying to decrypt the encrypted FVEK won't work (because it was re-encrypted with new VMK). Of course, depends how quick the attacker is and other circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the VMK always stored locally on the system? I mean with administrative privileges, you can obtain the KPs - but, at the same time you'd be able to obtain the VMK, either by dumping memory or using some tool?